# SQL Server CE error message

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I passed the following query to SQL Server CE via C# code, I used the following query string:

```
string query = "Create table R_and_R_2nd_(7518) (Manpower_Name NVARCHAR(50),
                Instance INT, Start NVARCHAR(30), [End] NVARCHAR(30));"
```

I get the following error:

> There was an error parsing the query.
>   [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 27,Token in error = 7518 ]

Is it because of the parenthesis in the table name or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid table identifier, doesn't like parentheses.

see here for definition [sql database identifiers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)